# Error g.extension GRASS GIS in Ubuntu

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu

I'm trying to install a module in GRASS GIS, the v.lidar.mcc, however the script g.extension is showing the following error below:

*

> g.extension extension=v.lidar.mcc url=
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/grass73/scripts/g.extension", line 1729, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/lib/grass73/scripts/g.extension", line 1704, in main
>       check_dirs()   File "/usr/lib/grass73/scripts/g.extension", line 1381, in check_dirs
>       check_style_files('grass_logo.png')   File "/usr/lib/grass73/scripts/g.extension", line 1355, in
>   check_style_files
>       shutil.copyfile(dist_file, addons_file)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
>       with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/grass73/docs/html/grass_logo.png'

*

I had installed this module normally in GRASS on Windows, however the UBUNTU am unsuccessful.

Anyone know how to solve it? I tried to update GRASS, install and uninstall, install via python but the error keeps popping up!

Comment: The message refer to a missing png file (grass_logo.png). You can try to find it on your machine or download it from the Internet (76 x 91 pixel). On my Ubuntu the grass_logo.png is there (grass70).

Comment: I'm trying this, but GRASS sent the following message:              g.extension extension=v.lidar.mcc url=                                          
Fetching <v.lidar.mcc> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
ERROR: Please install GRASS development package
(Thu Aug 18 17:02:50 2016) Comando terminado (8 sec)                                                  What can be done?

Comment: Do as it is written in the error log: `Please install GRASS development package`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I can't add any extension. I've uninstalled and reinstalled GRASS two times already but nothing happened. `sudo apt install grass-dev` outputs (google trad from french, don't mind the language errors) $ sudo apt install grass-dev Reading package lists ... Done Building the dependency tree Reading status information ... Done Some packages can not be installed. This can mean that you asked for the impossible, or, if you use the unstable distribution, that some packages have not yet were created or did not come out of Incoming. The following information should help yo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in [g.extension manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/g.extension.html):

> Since extensions have to be compiled on Unix based systems (Linux, Mac OSX etc.) unless a Python extension is installed, a full compiler environment must be present on the user's computer. While GRASS GIS is available on the user's computer, the respective development package is lacking. If GRASS was installed from a (Linux) repository, also the grass-dev* package (commonly named "grass-dev" or "grass-devel", sometimes along with the version number) must be installed.

So open your package manager and install that package.